# How to use c# like try catch in angular2 and post to server

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to post my all type of runtime errors to server.Can anyone pls guide me.I searched for it.I never get as I am expected.Kindly find below code

```
       ngOnInit()
       {  
          try{

               this.CallGetBreakingNews();
              }
           catch(e)
              {
            console.log(e);
               }
              }
            }


           CallGetBreakingNews() {
           this._service.GetBreakingNews().subscribe(
         res => {
           this._brNews = res;
           let _list: Array<BreakingNews> = [];
            for (let i = 0; i <=this._brNews.length; i++) {
         _list.push({
           id: this._brNews[i].id,
           name: this._brNews[i].name
          });
          }
          this._brNews = _list;
           });
          }
```

In CallGetBreakingNews method I put wrong condition as **i<=this._brNews.length**.It should go to catch right?.but It doesn't go.

Thanks

Comment: you should provide some minimal example code raising an error you want to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom error handler class and provide it for application:

main.ts for example:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() { }
  handleError(err) {
     // implement your custom logic here
     throw err;
  }  
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: CustomErrorHandler 
    }
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks.I wrote error in console log in handleError.I removed all other catches(observable catch).It should not throw any console error right.All error must be write from app.module.ts right?.But I got console error as "zone.js:2019 GET http://10.10.100.127:81/api/Setting/Region/RegionNames"  net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: This is helpful for me.other errors are catched and wrote from app.module.ts.can u pls help me to catch zone.js errors.

Comment: can i write this log to external file

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    tryCode - Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
    catchCode - Block of code to handle errors
} 
finally {
    finallyCode - Block of code to be executed regardless of the try / catch result
}
```

this is the the normal JS try/catch, it works the same way on angular.

Comment: Thanks,I am using typescript only.I used try catch like this.But it doesn't go to catch when error occurs

Comment: can you show me the code ? maybe the problem is in there .

Comment: if OP is using rxjs/Observables (or simple Promises), this would be handles differently